# Does the Worklight Server support storage of a JSON file?

Tags: database, json, caching, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm looking for a way to have a JSON file stored on the Worklight Server. The purpose for this is that it will be a JSON file accessed by many devices. On connection to the server, there will be an initial check against the database that drives the app to see what the version number is. If it's a match with what's currently in the JSON file, nothing will be done (in effect the 'cached' JSON file will be used). If there is no match however, the new JSON file will be pulled from the database.

Has anyone done this and does anyone know if it's possible? If anyone has any suggestions for how I may implement this I'd be really grateful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Worklight Server is more of a "conduit", using adapters, between applications and your backend. I do not think you should save anything on it. IMO, what you should do have some file server (not Worklight Server), that your adapter will fetch the JSON file from it.